# How do you import older versions of a module in Python?

Tags: python

I have been given a script which uses an older version of a Python module (MDAnalysis 0.1) than I normally use (MDAnalysis 0.17).

If I try and run the script with the usual module, I get runtime errors, and rewriting the script for the older module version in non-trivial.

So I'd like to be able to install and import different versions of MDAnalysis as and when I need them. Is this possible?

Comment: Use a *virtual environment* in which you install the necessary libraries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Makes sense - will give it a go. thanks.